# How to transform AVFrame to GstBuffer?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, gstreamer, libav, gstreamer-1.0

I want to push frames by `libav` (ffmpeg) to GStreamer `appsrc` element. The problem is how to transform `AVFrame` or `AVPicture` to `GstBuffer`. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:
[GstBuffer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstbuffer.html?gi-language=c#GstBuffer)
[AVFrame Struct Reference](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/structAVFrame.html) and 
[AVPicture Struct Reference](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.6/structAVPicture.html#details)

Steps to follow:

- clobber all relevant information from the AVFrame object
- create a GstBuffer object and set the relevant informations
- push the GstBuffer to appsrc

If you are unsure how to interpret the different fields of AVFrame and how they are used, navigate the reference pages and study the provided examples.

Be aware that the time units are in AVStream->time_base units. You probably have to rescale/convert them to the desired format of the gstreamer api.

By the way, why not stick with gstreamer? What's the purpose using two different media frameworks at the same time? Gstreamer has ffmpeg support (although considered as 'ugly').

[GStreamer FFmpeg plug-in](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-ffmpeg.html)